# Color specific term

Tags: vim, color-scheme

More specifically I would like the term "False" in python to be always colored red as opposed to the term "True" which is already green(as its "False", since both are part of the pythonBuiltin category I believe). So is there a way to determine a color only to a specific word? I want to keep my current colorscheme and only add this tweak.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I can't understand what you are talking about. Do you specifically mean that you want to control how the Vim program displays your Python code? Or something else? If so, you may find better help on [vi.se].

Comment: Thanks. Yea I would like to know if theres a way through vim to color just one specific word rather than a whole "syntax group".

Comment: Just spitballing, but did you try making a new syntax group that only contains that word?

Comment: See `:help syn-keyword` and, more generally, `:help syntax`.

Comment: Think I got it thx for the attention tho @KarlKnechtel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woops think I got it.
I added to my .vimrc:

```
highlight redOnes ctermfg=red
match redOnes /False/
```

:h match was helpful